# Emulating the special properties of sizeof with constexpr

Tags: c++

In C++ `sizeof` is somewhat unique in that it's legal to write this:

```
int x;
sizeof(x); // a variable
```

As well as simply:

```
sizeof(int); // a type
```

(There's a third even weirder variant I'd rather ignore for now though, with no parenthesis needed, since I'm pretty certain that is impossible to emulate)

I'd like to be able to replicate this behaviour myself. To motivate it I've got an example `bitsof` operator.

```
#include <climits>

template <typename T>
struct bits_traits {
  enum { value = sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT };
};

struct int_12_bit {
  enum { bits = 12 };
  // Let's pretent this has a bunch of code for looking and feeling like a 12bit int in a helpful and portable way
};

template <>
struct bits_traits<int_12_bit> {
  enum { value = int_12_bit::bits };
};

#define bitsof(x) bits_traits<x>::value

int main() {
  using std::size_t;
  size_t b = bitsof(int);
  size_t a = bitsof(int_12_bit);

  int_12_bit x;
  size_t c = bitsof(x); // <-- Not cool
}
```

Clearly I could have written the whole thing in terms of a macro, using sizeof, e.g.

```
#define bitsof(x) (sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT)
```

But then I lose the ability to "specialise" it.

And equally I could write `size_t c = bitsof(decltype(x))`. However what I'm asking here is for a way of emulating that behaviour in my own code without having to settle for a workaround. How can I write a `bitsof` that looks and feels like `sizeof`, but specialises like traits? Do I just have to accept that `sizeof` is a bit special and live with it?

I initially played with a few ideas:

1. Perhaps `decltype` works like `sizeof`, e.g. `decltype(0)` and `decltype(int)` are synonymous. No luck there though.
2. Maybe we could do something with pointer/reference template parameters. I couldn't see a way of getting deduction to work properly for that case though, and it would impose additional constraints on what variables we could use `bitsof` with.
3. Maybe some crazy SFINAE with a combination of templates and macros, but I can't see a way of making that happen, it's always just a syntax error.
4. Possibly something to workaround the limitations of one of the above using GCC's statement-expr extension.

As there's an easy workaround with `decltype` and more of a learning experiment I'm open to ideas using anything available in any C++ released compiler targeting any past, present or future standard.

Comment: `sizeof()` is a compiler intrinsic function, the compiler knows the difference between a type and a variable and adjusts its behavior accordingly.  You can't always emulate in user code what the compiler can do.  This is one of those cases. You will have to stick with using `decltype` when passing a variable to your template.

Comment: Otherwise, try changing your `bitsof()` macro into an overloaded templated function instead, eg: `template<typename T> size_t bitsof() { return bits_traits<T>::value; } template<typename T> size_t bitsof(const T &) { return bits_traits<T>::value; } ... size_t b = bitsof<int>(); ... int_12_bit x; size_t c = bitsof(x);` Or don't overload at all: `template<typename T> size_t bitsof_type() { return bits_traits<T>::value; } template<typename T> size_t bitsof_variable(const T &) { return bits_traits<T>::value; } ... size_t b = bitsof_type<int>(); ... int_12_bit x; size_t c = bitsof_variable(x);`

Comment: Under the hood, types and expressions are _very_ different. I doubt it's possible to do this without using non-standard extensions like tkausl suggested. If one day decltype accepts types directly, it would be trivial. We can only dream.

Comment: Not sure what you're referring to with the "third even weirder variant" comment. `sizeof` is an operator; the parentheses are superfluous in all cases (notwithstanding precedence considerations, as is usual for any expression). `sizeof(int)` is `sizeof (int)` is `sizeof int`. It ain't a function.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `int x = sizeof int;` won't compile and isn't legal. `int x = sizeof x;` is legal. Does that not seem even a little bit weird? With a blank slate designing a language I'd make the parenthesis mandatory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

#define bitsof(k) decltype(bitsof_left+(k)+bitsof_right)

template <class K>
struct bits_traits { /* whatever you want here */ };

struct bitsof_left_t {
    template <class T>
    bits_traits<T> operator+(const T&);
} bitsof_left;

struct bitsof_right_t {
    template <class T>
    friend T operator+(const T&, bitsof_right_t);

    bitsof_right_t operator+();

    template <class T>
    operator T() const;

} bitsof_right;

int main()
{
    using foo = bitsof(42);
    using bar = bitsof(int);

    static_assert(std::is_same<foo, bits_traits<int>>::value);
    static_assert(std::is_same<bar, bits_traits<int>>::value);
}
```

It works like this.

`a + (42) + b` is parsed as `(a + (42)) + b)`, then overloaded binary `operator+` at either side kicks in. In my example the operators are only declared, not defined, but since it's unevaluated context, it doesn't matter.

`a + (int) + b` is parsed as `a + ((int) (+ b))`. Here we employ the overloaded unary + at the right side, then overloaded cast operator, then overloaded binary + at the left side.

Comment: Has this trick been documented before? Or is it your idea? Nice!

Comment: This looks like black magic. How is something like `decltype(5+(int)+5)` parsed? Very cool.

Comment: It does look like black magic! It seems the `(int)+bitof_right` is first parsed by `bitsof_right_t operator+();` to get rid of the `+` (?), then by `operator T() const;` into nothing (?). I'm not sure... would really like a definitive explanation.

Comment: @Edy The expression `bitsof_right` is of type `bitsof_right_t` which supports unary plus, so `+bitsof_right` is just a `bitsof_right_t` (of unknown value due to missing operator definition, but that doesn't matter since this is an "unevaluated context"), which is then cast to `int`. So you've ended up with `decltype(bitsof_left + int())` and you can apply a similiar direction of logic to evaluate the rest. This is really clever. Different but not dissimilar rules allow the same logic to work when `k` is an expression rather than a type (via _binary_ `+`)

Comment: This is neat and looks nothing like any of the ideas I played with when experimenting on this. I'm tempted to generalise it into an equivalent of `decltype` with semantics that permits having types as well as expressions as the input.

Comment: My plan now is to run with a simplified form of your answer that does a generalised '`typeof`', and then implement my `bitsof` in terms of that `typeof`. https://gist.github.com/fflexo/e2385bd2ce1651d91682543ea0a04592

Answer (score 2):

Its hard and probably impossible, mainly because you can only pass compile-time constants as template values to templates, hence your last example with the `int_12_bit x;` will never be able to be a template value (and types can't be passed as parameters, of course). I played around a bit with `decltype`, `declval` and different templates, but I simply could not get it to take in types **and** (non-constand expression) values with a single "call". It's really unfortunate `decltype` doesn't accept types, I wonder why the committee choose to only accept expressions.

Since you mentioned `gcc`-extensions, there is an extension which can make it work, `__typeof__`.

I personally have never used this extension, but it seems like it works similar to `decltype` but it also accepts types directly.

This snipped compiles under gcc x86-64 8.3 for me:

```
template<typename T>
struct bits_trait;

template<>
struct bits_trait<int>{};

void f() {
    int x;
    bits_trait<__typeof__(x)>();
    bits_trait<__typeof__(int)>();
}
```

But this will only compile under gcc.

Edit: Clang seems to support it as well, no luck with MSVC though.

Answer (score 1):

Not considering macros and without `decltype`, it is simply not possible because of the language syntax.

However you can get pretty damn close:

```
template <class T>
constexpr auto bitsof(T) { return sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT; }

template <>
constexpr auto bitsof(int_12_bit) { return 12; }

template <class T>
constexpr auto bitsof() { return sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT; }

template <>
constexpr auto bitsof<int_12_bit>() { return 12; }
```

```
auto test()
{
    constexpr int a{};
    constexpr int_12_bit x{};

    static_assert(bitsof(a) == 32);
    static_assert(bitsof(x) == 12);

    static_assert(bitsof<int>() == 32);
    static_assert(bitsof<int_12_bit>() == 12);
}
```

Aside from the slightly different syntax (but c'mon it's so close it shouldn't really matter) the biggest difference to the `sizeof` is that the arguments are not in an unevaluated context. So `bitsof(foo())` will call `foo()`. And `bitsof(a)` is UB if `a` is uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon the [quite magical answer from n.m.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55132015/4509057), with just tiny bit of massage, it seems it *is* possible to have `bitsof` mimic `sizeof`.

```
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct bits_traits {
  enum { value = sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT };
};

struct int_12_bit {
  enum { bits = 12 };
};

template <>
struct bits_traits<int_12_bit> {
  enum { value = int_12_bit::bits };
};

#define bits_traits_of(k) decltype(bits_traits_of_left+(k)+bits_traits_of_right)

struct bits_traits_of_left_t {
    template <class T>
    bits_traits<T> operator+(const T&);
} bits_traits_of_left;

struct bits_traits_of_right_t {
    template <class T>
    friend T operator+(const T&, bits_traits_of_right_t);

    bits_traits_of_right_t operator+();

    template <class T>
    operator T() const;

} bits_traits_of_right;

#define bitsof(x) bits_traits_of(x)::value

int main() {
  using std::size_t;
  size_t a = bitsof(int);
  size_t b = bitsof(int_12_bit);
  std::cout <<"a="<< a <<", b="<< b << std::endl;

  int_12_bit x;
  size_t c = bitsof(x);
  std::cout <<"c="<< c << std::endl;
}
```

The only thing that I changed, other than adding in definitions for `bits_traits`, is to redefine `bitsof` so that it returns the `bits_traits::value` rather than the `bits_traits` type.

```
$ ./a.out 
a=32, b=12
c=12
```

I'm just writing this up to verify that it *can* work. All credits should go to [n.m.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55132015/4509057).