# Having a Template take either a Type or a value

Tags: c++, templates

I want to make a MemoryPool to dynamically assign and deassign memory in runtime without involving the OS in an attempt to speed up code execution (and learn). To simplyfy the syntax i'd like to be able to specify the size of memory segments either as the type they contain or as a raw size.

To do this i want to make a template that can take either a Type or a size_t and sends onwards either the sizeof Type or the size.

```cpp
template<size_t SegmentSize>
class MemoryPool_Internal
{
public:
    static const size_t Size = SegmentSize;
    /*Using SegmentSize to do logic*/
};

template<size_t Size>
class MemoryPool : public MemoryPool_Internal<Size> { };

template<class Size>
class MemoryPool : public MemoryPool_Internal<sizeof(Size)> { };
```

What i'd like to happen with the above snippet is to have

```cpp
std::cout << MemoryPool<5>::Size << std::endl;
std::cout << MemoryPool<int>::Size << std::endl;
```

To print 5 and sizeof(int).

But 5 raises C3855 because its not a class and int raises E0254 because type is not allowed in the first template. 
Is there any way to resolve this during compile time to the intended templates for each?

Comment: You need a C++17 compiler, and use an `auto` template parameter.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik what won't solve the issue as it will accept only values

Comment: There's no "overloading" for templates.

Comment: By the way, why can't you just use the `size_t` variant, and explicitly use `sizeof(int)` directly when instantiating the template?

Comment: Seems duplicately enough https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55350862/c-how-do-you-overload-a-template-to-work-for-both-value-and-type

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do this exactly like that. The language doesn't allow this kind of syntax. What you can do however use only type templates and create a type to hold the explicit size:

```
template <std::size_t SegmentSize>
struct ExplicitSize
{
    static constexpr auto Size = SegmentSize;
};

template <class T>
constexpr std::size_t SegmentSize = sizeof(T);
template <std::size_t Size>
constexpr std::size_t SegmentSize<ExplicitSize<Size>> = Size;


template<class SizeSpecifier>
class MemoryPool_Internal
{
public:
    static const size_t Size = SegmentSize<SizeSpecifier>;
    /*Using Size to do logic*/
};

static_assert(MemoryPool_Internal<ExplicitSize<32>>::Size == 32);
static_assert(MemoryPool_Internal<int>::Size == sizeof(int));
```

Or, alternately use only value templates and use `sizeof`:

```
MemoryPool_Internal<32>
MemoryPool_Internal<sizeof(int)>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem stems from trying to use the same name for two different template classes.

Using different names for different types of memory pool is the only solution here, I think (and in my opinion is less ambiguous when reading the code later):

```
template< size_t SIZE >
class MemoryPool_Internal
{
public:
    static const size_t Size = SIZE;
    /*Using SegmentSize to do logic*/
};

template< size_t SIZE >
class SizedMemoryPool : public MemoryPool_Internal< SIZE > { };

template< typename TYPE >
class TypedMemoryPool : public MemoryPool_Internal< sizeof( TYPE )> { };
```

The above worked for me - outputting 5 and 4 for your test, respectively.

Comment: This is neat and simple, and likely what i'll end up doing. But it creates a bit of ambiguity when trying to use the class.