# Issue specializing template with type and value

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have written the following classes

```
#include <tuple>

class AbstractEvent
{
public:
    using ID = int;

public:
    virtual ~AbstractEvent() = default;
    ID id() const { return id_; }

protected:
    explicit AbstractEvent(ID id) : id_(id) {}

private:
    ID id_;
};

template <AbstractEvent::ID ID_>
class Event : public AbstractEvent
{
public:
    static constexpr auto kID = ID_;
    Event() : AbstractEvent(kID) {}
};

template <typename T, typename ... ARGS>
class BasicEvent;

template <AbstractEvent::ID ID_, typename ... ARGS>
class BasicEvent<Event<ID_>, ARGS...> : public Event<ID_>
{
public:
    explicit BasicEvent(ARGS... args) : _args(std::move(args)...) {}

    ~BasicEvent() = default;

    template <unsigned int INDEX_ = 0>
    inline const auto& arg() const
    {
        return std::get<INDEX_>(_args);
    }
    
    template <unsigned int INDEX_ = 0>
    inline auto& arg()
    {
        return std::get<INDEX_>(_args);
    }

private:
    std::tuple<ARGS...> _args;
};

struct Events
{
    enum : AbstractEvent::ID
    {
        Event1ID,
        Event2ID,
    };
    using Event1 = Event<Event1ID>;
    using Event2 = Event<Event2ID>;
};
```

My goal was to special the `BasicEvent` template so that I can pass either an "event ID" value or an `Event` class to it like so

```
class Event1 : public BasicEvent<Events::Event1ID> {};
```

or

```
class Event1 : public BasicEvent<Events::Event1> {};
```

However, the first example (using the ID) results in the following compile error on CLang:

```
template argument for template type parameter must be a type
```

and on GCC

```
type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class T, class ... ARGS> class BasicEvent'
```

This doesn't make sense to me.  If I specialize the `BasicEvent` class to take a value, shouldn't the `BasicEvent<Event<ID_>, ARGS...>`  match the `template <typename T, typename ... ARGS> class BasicEvent;` template?

Comment: You can't mix type and non-type template parameters like this.  You either take a type, or you take a value, there is not a way to take either or.

Comment: @NathanOliver I was not aware of this.  Can you point me to the relevant part of the C++ standard that talks about this so I can do some more reading?

Comment: Related/dupes: [Having a Template take either a Type or a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55472957/having-a-template-take-either-a-type-or-a-value) and [C++ how do you "overload" a template to work for both value and type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55350862/c-how-do-you-overload-a-template-to-work-for-both-value-and-type)

Comment: The dupe was right. You can't overload a template like this.

Comment: @PatrickWright I'm not sure which sections apply exactly, but your primary template requires a type.  When the compiler looks and see you've given it a value it's not going to care that there is a specialization that can take a value, it still expects a type in order to match.  The specialization is only considered after the compiler deduces the primary template is the correct template name to use.

Comment: You can't "specialize" a template to have different kinds of parameters, only to specific arguments. See [footnote 4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.decls#temp.class.general-4) of `temp.class.general` in the most recent draft.